# Inheritance at EF code first create an unexpected cast at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, runtime, code-first

I have this:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Student : Person
{       
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Account AccountInformation { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set;}
}
```

And in `DbContext` class:

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

After update-database three tables are made: `Person` , `Student`(with the same Primary Key) and `Account`.

I want to fetch Person, but in run-time i have Student object.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                Person person = dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == 'myName');
                person.Name = "newName";
                dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Exception because student's `Email` is `Required`
            }
```

`person` in run-time is `Student`!!!
This causes errors when save time. because student's `Email` is `Required`.
Why this happen? and What should I do?

Comment: `What should I do?` reconsider if you really want to use inheritance.

Comment: @Stefan No, there's nothing wrong using inheritance here, I do this all the time.

Comment: Also there's nothing wrong with the code shown above. Are you doing something odd in the `OnModelCreating` event?

Comment: @DavidG: just to teach me, but, is this setup really helpful? If you don't know if a person is a student (or teacher, or ... etc) and you only have an `Id`, you will need to search multiple tables unless you store them in `persons` as well... or am I mistaken?

Comment: post updated.navigation property 'AccountInformation' caused this error to occur. because not included.

Comment: You should produce a simple, complete repro of the issue.  When you do you should discover your mistake.  Otherwise post it in your question, along with the error details, and someone else can.